# How do I print words from a (void *) string

Tags: c, printf, void

I am trying to work with a program that reads in text (Hindi or any other non-English language) into a data structure. The part that points to this text is a `void *` pointer. How can I use `fprintf` to print a sub-string of this text?

EDIT:

```
/* some text manipulation stuff. */
    wchar_t *origString = L"इसरो ने लॉन्च किया पहला 'मेड इन इंडिया' स्पेस शटल, PM बोले- ये असाधारण और प्रेरणादायक काम";
    void *pText = (void *)origString;
    wchar_t *newString = (wchar_t*)pText;
    fprintf(stdout, "Old String: %ls\n", origString);
    fprintf(stdout, "New string: %ls\n", newString);
```

In the output, I see only special, unprintable characters (not the UTF-8 encoding I am expecting).

EDIT:
I am using some third-party code to read in text (in a non-English language) and process it further. I also need to display this text on console.
Here is what the third-party code is doing:
1. Gets the size of the file.
2. Reads in (via `fread`), the entire text and uses `void *` to point to this blob.
3. I am trying to figure out how to manipulate this text - how do I even get it to print?

Comment: cast it to a (char*) pointer

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have, please post what you have tried.

Comment: `fwrite(pointer, 1, length, stdout);` does not require a cast nor `null` terminated data.

Comment: What encoding is the data?

Comment: @GiladNaaman: I have added an example. The text is Hindi. It should be UTF-8.

Comment: The example you added doesn't make much sense... You have a wchar_t * (which isn't UTF-8, it is either UTF-16 on Windows or UTF-32 on Linux), you cast it to a void * and then back to wchar_t *, and then you print it with `%ls` (which is ok for "wide" strings, but not for UTF-8). Could you provide an example that is a bit more related to the situation you are describing? Are you reading UTF-8 or something else?

Comment: At least in C those casts are useless. They have no effect but obfuscating the code, and/or hiding errors. Just remove them.

Comment: @All: I agree with what you are saying. I added more details about what the code is doing.

Comment: Let me see if I understand what you want to do: You have code that reads Hindi text from a file, which it hands you as a byte array (from fread), and you want to convert that text to UTF-8 and print it? Is that correct? Are there any text constants (like origString) in the source code at all? What encoding is the input data in? If you can, please show more code.

Comment: @Enno: Yes. That is correct. I tried to do `File->Save As` on Notepad. The encoding there was "Unicode". I am assuming this text is also in Unicode? I am not able to show more code... sorry..

Answer (score 5):

Arbitrary wide char strings will not be convertable to something you can output except in a UTF-8 based locale. At program startup the initial locale is "C". You must call `setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"")` to activate the default locale for character encoding , which on a modern system should be UTF-8 based. (As I had originally stated, you could alternatively use `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` to activate all locale categories, not just character encoding, but that has lots of consequences you might not want like potentially breaking all functions that work with decimal points.)

`void *` and the casts are irrelevant to your question. Converting between pointer types does not convert the data they point to.

Comment: Please, just do `LC_CTYPE`, not `LC_ALL`. Setting `LC_NUMERIC` breaks any numeric function (down to `strtod`), and there's no thread-safe way around it. Or just output UTF-8 and just pretend that this sad encoding stuff never happened.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Thanks. I've changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

> print a sub-string of this text

Just cast pointer as needed and provide substring length:

```
FILE *out; /* init FILE */
void *pointer; /* init pv */;
size_t offset; /* start of substring */
unsigned length; /* substring length */
fprintf(out, "%*s", length, (char *) pointer + offset);
```

Comment: One of the rare cases one needs to cast in C.

Comment: Mind that you cannot just take any substring of a UTF-8 string and expect it to be a valid UTF-8 string, because your substring offset might split up a multi-byte symbol. In other words, if OPs goal is to split on character boundaries, the problem becomes more complex.